# Dialogflow navigate through conversation using fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent that is triggering the fulfillment logic which based on the extracted entities and intent name should decide which text and which custom payload should be returned to the client. 
Example:

**intent A(to fulfillment)**: I want to buy some eggs(entity)

**fulfillment**:

```
if we_have_eggs_in_store
   go to intent A
else 
   go to intent B
```

**intent A**: How many eggs you want?
**intent B**: We currently don't have any eggs in our store...

constraints: 
1. I don't want to store the response text in the fulfillment 
2. I want to pass custom payload back to the client

Is this possible to achieve with the Dialogflow?